# What's the best way to reference an element via ID in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, reference

Should I be using `$("#myElement")` or `$(myElement)`? Both appear to work.

Comment: Hey @Tom, please accept the answers that are most helpful to you. Just click on the hollow checkmark next to the answer!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**EDIT**: `$('#myElement')` selects the element in the DOM which has an `id` of `myElement`, while `$(myElement)` expects that the JavaScript identifier `myElement` be a `DOMElement` object or a `string` containing the selector.

Comment: My bad, I meant to say $("#myElement") or $(myElement)—which is better or more widely used (both seem to work)?

Comment: The former. You need to prefix the element with a `#` or `.` if it is an ID or class respectively.

Comment: To whoever downvoted my answer, the OP's original question had a `#(myElement)` in it, that's what my response was to.

Comment: `myElement` can also be a variable containing a jQuery selector string in the case of `$(myElement)`... see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the jQuery **[selectors page](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)** as your reference.

There are a lot of selectors to choose from. Try out each one. Here's the two you reference in your question with 2 others:

```
$("#myElement")    // select and element with the ID "myElement"
$(myElement)       // use the variable myElement as your jQuery selector

$(document)        // The selector can also a DOM OBJECT
                   // document, window ...

$("body")          // To select a DOM element use this form
```

For example this will hide all the paragraphs on a page. Since the variable `myElement` is `"p"`, `$(myElement)` will select all paragraphs on the page into a jQuery object.

```
var myElement = "p";
$(myElement).hide();
```

### **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/6YMpG/)**

This will alert the visible width of the window:

```
alert($(window).width());
```

This will alert the contents of the DIV with an ID of `myElement`

```
alert($("#myElement").html());
```

All of this means that `$("#myElement")` will only select the same thing as `$(myElement)` if the variable `myElement` is `"#myElement"` or functions in an equivalent manner.